# How to return part of the string in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to return maximum 9 digits of the following abc string .How to do this?

```
public string test()
{
  string abc="asdhfjsdfkjhfiovjalksdhafbvklxkjszjhd";
  return abc;
}
```

Comment: Well  there are no digits in string. Can try substring

Answer (score 5):

Use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public string test()
{
  string abc="asdhfjsdfkjhfiovjalksdhafbvklxkjszjhd";
  return abc.Substring(0, 9);
}
```

Comment: no.... this is not what he wants

Comment: Oops, you're right...

Answer (score 5):

```
public string test()
{
  string abc="asdhfjsdfkjhfiovjalksdhafbvklxkjszjhd";
  return abc.Substring(0,9);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as answered by others

Other than that

```
public string test()
{
  string abc = "asdhfjsdfkjhfiovjalksdhafbvklxkjszjhd";
        abc = new string(abc.Take(9).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

you can use this:

```
public string test()
{
  string abc="asdhfjsdfkjhfiovjalksdhafbvklxkjszjhd";
  abc = abc.Substring(0, 9);
  return abc;
}
```